# How and where is the $variables variable used in templates etc. generated in Drupal?

Tags: theming

How and where is the `$variables` variables that is used in templates and theme functions generated in Drupal?

Is there documentation anywhere that defines `$variables`?

Comment: It really depends on which variables you're interested in. It's a bit too vague for a question.

Comment: Do you mean it depends on what key-value pairs of $variables I'm interested in? So, for example, where is $variables created that is passed into theme_item_list (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7)?

Comment: The `$variables` for `theme_item_list` will have originated from the function that calls `theme('item_list', $variables);`. Which variables are accepted will have been declared in `hook_theme()`. Also have a look at [`theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7)

Answer (score 1):

The `$variables` associated array that are passed into functions such as `MYTHEME_item_list($variables)` are initialized by the caller of that function.

Comment: I think OP is talking about the `$variables` array that gets passed to theme functions/templates.

Comment: I have revoked my downvote :-)

Comment: Thanks. So essentially, the contents of $variables will be set by modules and passed to theme functions/templates to be rendered into HTML?

Answer (score -1):

You can use associated array $variables that are taken from template.php or yourmodule.module so that, you can pass that variables to page of your theme.

```
 $imageOutputinner = “You can have  images variable here”;
$vars['innerImages'] = $imageOutputinner;
//you can print this variables to page of  theme as
print_r($innerImages);
```